# Using Log4cplus for C++, logging is paused when 3rd party method is called and log file is truncated

Tags: c++, logging, log4cplus, truncate-log

When 3rd party method is called, i get the below error. Looks like there is problem with the file handle when 3rd party function is called. Later, logging starts after 1 or 2 secs.

07/22/14 12:00:22 [5944] DEBUG   log4cplus:ERROR file is not open
:

How do I resolve this?

1. List item

Comment: Please post some sample code that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: <logging happends before the Vector operations          vector<float> coeff(4);
Scalar sumMat = sum(depth);
int eleVal = operations

subtract(*VERT, Scalar(eleVal), depth);   //Vector subtract

Comment: StackOverflow tries hard to be a question-and-answer site rather than a forum.  To get answers, it's very helpful to put all of the information in the question (not in comments).  Please edit your question and add (1) properly formatted code that (2) if possible, can be run and reproduces the problem (see http://sscce.org/) and (3) name and link to the libraries you're using.